Trigonometric integral with a square root
I'm trying to compute this integral :
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{\pi/2}\left[\rule{0pt}{5mm}2\cos^{2}\left(x\right)
\sin\left(x\right) + 8\cos^{3}\left(x\right)\sin^{2}\left(x\right) +
2\cos\left(x\right)\sin^{2}\left(x\right)\right.
\\ & \left.\rule{0pt}{5mm}\phantom{aaa\,}+ 8 \cos^{2}\left(x\right)\sin^{3}\left(x\right)
\right]\,\sqrt{\,2\cos\left(x\right)
\sin\left(x\right)\,}\,\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

I've tried to let $t = \tan\left(x/2\right)$ and to use the formula
$$
\sin\left(x\right)  = {2t \over 1 + t^{2}}\quad \mbox{and}\quad\cos\left(x\right) = {1 - t^{2} \over 1 + t^{2}}
$$
but the square root is still causing problems$\ldots$
How would you do to compute this kind of thing ?.

Thanks in advance for your answer !.

You need to solve $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{m+{1}/{2}}{x} \sin^{n+{1}/{2}}{x} dx$$ in only one of the two cases:     (1) $m$ is odd and $n$ is even          (2) $m$ is even and $n$ is odd.  Notice that you can switch the sines into cosines and cosines into sines in the integrand. Can you do that ?

I don't see how I could solve this...

Can you solve $\int_{0}^{1}t^{\lambda} \sqrt{1-t^2}dt$ where $\lambda>1$ by changing variables $1-t^{2}\rightarrow s^{2}$ ? You need to change variables first, say $\cos{x}\rightarrow t$. See it now?

See also the beta function

For $\int_0^{\pi/2}2\cos^{2}\left(x\right)
\sin\left(x\right) \sqrt{,2\cos\left(x\right)
\sin\left(x\right)} {d}x$, I get $4  \sqrt{2} \int_0^1t^2 \sqrt{t}: \left(1-t^2\right)^{1/4} dt$ when letting $t= \cos(x)$... and I dont see how I can manage with that....

Notice that
$$\begin{align*}
2c^2s + 8c^3s^2 + 2cs^2 + 8c^2s^3 &= 2cs (c+s + 4cs(c+s)) \\
&= 2cs(c+s)(1+4cs)
\end{align*}$$
where $c=\cos x$ and $s=\sin x$. The integrand may thus be rewritten as
$$\sqrt2 \, \sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right) \left(1+2\sin(2x)\right) (\sin(2x))^{3/2}$$
with the identities $\sin(2x)=2cs$ and $\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\dfrac\pi4\right)=c+s$. The latter in particular motivates substituting $y=x+\dfrac\pi4$, which transforms the integral to
$$\int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \cdots \, dx = \sqrt2 \int_{-\tfrac\pi4}^\tfrac\pi4 \cos y (1+2\cos(2y)) (\cos(2y))^{3/2} \, dy$$
Can you continue with this?

Thanks for your answer.

I get then $\int_{-pi/4}^{pi/4} \cos(y) \cos(2y) \sqrt{\cos(2y)} dy = \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \cos(y) (1-2 \sin^2(y)) \sqrt{1-2 \sin^2(y)} dy = \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \cos(y) \left[(1- (\sqrt{2}\sin(y))^2\right] \sqrt{1- (\sqrt{2}\sin(y))^2} dy = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{-1}^{1} (1-u^2) \sqrt{1-u^2} du = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^4(t) dt$ (which is a quite usual integral) by letting $u=\sqrt{2} \sin(y)$ and, then, $u=\sin(t)$.
